# Scratch card number & serial generator

Tags: algorithm, security

In a company, We need to make scratch cards similar to the ones available in the market.

- there is number hidden which needs to be scratched.
- Serial number which is visible.

My question is very basic that how do other companies make those hidden and serial numbers. I have read little bit about hashing but couldn't connect the dots.

1. Is the serial number independent of the invisible part?
2. Do they take a serial number and hash that to make the invisible part or vice versa?

and also,

1. How are invisible numbers made? like what algorithm is commonly used for that?

Any insight will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: As illustrated by a recent Wired article, if you make it so that it is in any way possible to determine if a ticket is a winner by looking at the serial number, somebody is sure to find that out sooner or later.

Comment: Typically, there is no algorithm tying the visible number with the hidden number. The two numbers are only tied together in a database record on a server.

Comment: @MarcusAdams right thanks, do you know how the invisible numbers are generated? like which algo is used make 14 digit random numbers? Some kind of pseudo random number generator?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Please explain how? What if I put hashed value in serial space?

Comment: Today, SHA1 (or stronger) hashes for serials would be fine (as long as the other number was randomly generated). However, if they have a long shelf life, do you want to be at risk when someone cracks the algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

Scratch card number and Serial number are independent of each other. 
They are just for proving the authentication of the scratch card.At the server end both serial number and scratch card number are matched and if they get matched then only further operation/activity takes place.

Scratch Card number is generated by Random Number Generation algo.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to use a cryptographically secure random number generator to prevent somebody from buying a small batch of cards and figuring out what the sequence of numbers are.  A normal random number generator is **NOT** sufficient!